# Redux.js - Build a listener middleware who listens for thunk action dispatched

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, middleware

I'm trying  to build a listener middleware with Redux who listen for thunk action dispatched.

The objective is that when a action is dispatched, the middleware make pause on the process and trigger and  another action  (the observer). I have found 
a seemingly nice [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-listeners) on NPM but seems my observer doesn't grabs the dispatched action. When the first action is dispatched, nothing happen it seems the the listener is even didn't triggered.

I have ensured my middleware is effectively injected in the store.

Here my code abstracts :

react.js :

```
import { createMiddleware } from 'redux-listeners';
const listenMiddleware = createMiddleware(); 

listenMiddleware.addListener(POST_WORD_REQUEST, (dispatch) => {     
  // postFile is the listener action 
  // provided by mapDispatchToProps in an another file
  this.props.postFile(word, base64Data)
})
```

reduxAction.js :

```
// postWord is the observed action
export const postWord =  {...}  => {
    dispatch({
      type: POST_WORD_REQUEST,
      status: request
    });
}
```

middleware.js :

```
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'
import {applyMiddleware} from "redux"

import { createMiddleware } from 'redux-listeners';
const listenMiddleware = createMiddleware();

const middleware = applyMiddleware(
  listenMiddleware,
  thunkMiddleware
)

export default middleware // then createStore(appReducer, initialState, middleware)
```

Comment: Can you show the actual implementation of `listenMiddleware` ?  Is it an instance of that library, or something else?

Comment: Also, a middleware isn't a component, and won't have `this.props` at all.

Comment: Hi markerikson I have edited my post

Comment: Two suggestions:  1) add a `console.log()` statement in your listener callback to see if it's running, and 2) remove the `this.props` part because that doesn't exist in a middleware.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the this.props is here because the action is provided to my React component vie a mapDispatchToProps method, 

I wonder if it is possibe to mapDispatch a middleware to a component also because it seem like the component isn't aware of the middleware, the console.log doesn't returns nothing

Comment: That's what I'm saying.  A middleware doesn't have props, and it doesn't have a `mapDispatchToProps`. You can't call a function in a middleware that way.  The important question at the moment is, does your listener run when that action is dispatched?

Comment: Okay I see ... no the listener doesn't run when the action is dispatched, even the console log is failed to be reached, other thing strange, I got to re-import the middleware in my react.js file, however the middleware is in the store and the store is Provided to the whole app so seems strange to me that I have to re-import the middleware in my React.component, either I grab a "listenMiddleware" is undefined

Comment: Okay I understand now, I had just to import the listenerMiddleware from my store.js file, seems that it got to be directly link in memory to the original listenerMiddleware passed in the store vie applyMiddleware. Work now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing the issues from the discussion, as an answer:

- The callback provided to the `listenerMiddleware` instance was wrongly using `this.props`, which won't exist because it's not in a component
- It seems that two different instances of the middleware were being created, and the listener was being added to an instance of the middleware that *wasn't* being hooked up to the store.

Now, having said that: it seems like you're trying to trigger behavior in a React component based on a Redux action that was dispatched.  As you noted, this is "strange", and not a recommended way to structure your application.  I'd suggest finding another way to do things if possible.

Comment: the objective is to mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps a component in React °connect method in react-redux° in order to connect differents parts of my apps, hope my precisions will help